# Find homogeneous system of equations (and corresponding augmented matrix) with solution of span of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to find system of linear equations and then augmented matrix representing this system of equations to get desired linear span.

I want to find a system of equations such that the solution is exactly the linear span of vectors:

\begin{align}
    \begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
           1 \\
           0 \\
         \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
           0 \\
           1 \\
           2 \\
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}

Because we have span of two vectors in 3 dimensional space, we get 2 free variables, which means 1 equation. Basically we are looking for equation in the form: $ax + by + cz = 0$.

So I was looking at the problem as solving two equations:

1. $1a + 1b + 0c = 0$,
2. $0a + 1b + 2c = 0$.

From that we obtain:

$b = -a$ and $c = \frac{a}{2}$.

Setting for example: $a = 1$, we get equation: $x - y + \frac{z}{2} = 0$.

Rewriting it into augmented matrix:

\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & -1 & \frac{1}{2} &\bigm| & 0
\end{pmatrix}

But, kernel of this matrix is:

\begin{align}
    \begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
           1 \\
           0 \\
         \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
           -\frac{1}{2} \\
           0 \\
           1 \\
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}

I would like to find out where I am doing mistake. Is it in calculating the system of equations or rewriting it into matrix?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you made any mistakes; you just didn't realize your vectors actually have the same linear span as the desired two. Note $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} = 2 \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{1}{2} \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Thanks, haven't realized that linear spans are same this way, but this makes sense.